# Color scheme won't fully source from .vimrc

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme

I just added a few things to my `colorscheme.vim` which is sourced from my `.vimrc`.  In fact, it is the *last line* in the `.vimrc`.<sup>1</sup>

```
source ~/.vim/colorscheme.vim
```

Oddly, now *most* of it doesn't apply, yet some of it obviously does.  If I manually `:source ~/.vim/colorscheme.vim` it works, and so the only solution I've found is to add a keybinding for that.  I.e., now everytime I start the editor I have to manually load the colorscheme.

Here's `colorscheme.vim`.  The stuff I added was mostly for `Diff` but a few other things got tweaked.  Loaded manually, it all seems to work.

```
hi ColorColumn guibg=Black guifg=#dbdbdb ctermbg=black ctermfg=yellow
hi Comment ctermbg=gray ctermfg=darkblue guibg=#dbbdbd guifg=#000088
hi Conditional cterm=bold ctermfg=yellow gui=bold guifg=#ffff00
hi Constant ctermfg=brown guifg=#ff8800
hi Cursor guibg=#ff0000 guifg=#ffff00
hi Directory ctermfg=gray
hi DiffAdd guibg=#000044 guifg=#ffff00
hi DiffChange guibg=#000044 guifg=#aaaaaa
hi DiffDelete guibg=#000044 guifg=#008888
hi DiffText guibg=#884400 guifg=#ff8800
hi ErrorMsg ctermbg=red ctermfg=cyan cterm=bold guibg=#880000 guifg=#ffffff gui=bold
hi Folded guibg=#00ff00 guifg=#3300aa ctermbg=blue ctermfg=green
hi Identifier ctermfg=darkgreen gui=none guifg=#449944
hi LineNr ctermbg=black ctermfg=darkblue guibg=#111111 guifg=#444444
hi NonText ctermfg=red guifg=#ff8800
hi Normal guibg=#222228 guifg=#dbdbdb
hi Number cterm=underline ctermfg=green gui=underline guifg=#00ff00
hi PreProc cterm=bold guifg=#cccc88 
hi Repeat cterm=bold ctermfg=cyan gui=bold guifg=#00ffff
hi StatusLine cterm=bold ctermfg=green ctermbg=darkmagenta guibg=#aa00aa guifg=#00ff00
hi StatusLineNC ctermfg=7 ctermbg=black
hi Special ctermfg=magenta gui=bold guifg=#ff0088 guibg=#303030
hi SpecialKey ctermfg=darkblue guifg=#111111
hi SpellBad ctermbg=gray ctermfg=darkred
hi Statement ctermfg=gray guifg=#448888 
hi Type ctermfg=darkcyan guifg=#dd88dd gui=italic

if has("gui_running")
        set guioptions -=r
        set guioptions +=l
        set guioptions -=T
endif
```

A weird thing about "some of it" working is that it includes, e.g., `SpellBad`, which is near the end.  So it is not flaking out at some point, it is just ignoring or overriding most of the other stuff.

This applies to both console vim and gvim.

---

<sup>1. Note that **there were no changes made to `.vimrc`**, although since then I've tried moving that line to the top, etc., but this did not make any difference.</sup>

Comment: How are you sourcing it in `.vimrc`? What is the output of `:scriptnames` before you manually load it?

Comment: I've edited that in at the top.  As indicated, *nothing* in vimrc was edited when I did this.  The output of `scriptnames` includes it in order with other sourced scripts and does not change before or after sourcing it manually.

Comment: `:help hi-normal-cterm` recommends setting the colors for Normal first, before setting any other colors. My first suggestion is to move the `hi Normal ...` line to the top of the `hi` list. Next, I would set your colorscheme from your `~/.vimrc` by executing `colorscheme colorscheme` rather than by sourcing the file so as to pick up any other steps Vim thinks is necessary when setting a colorscheme. Not that other approaches won't work, but if you're having trouble, the closer your attempt is to the "standard" solution, the better chance you will have finding someone who can spot the problem.

Comment: @garyjohn When I added those new lines I alphabetized everything -- something I had forgotten but your *explanation* reminded me.  However, moving "Normal" to the top didn't fix anything.  What did is sourcing it via `colorscheme` (regardless of where `Normal` is).  I fear my use of the term "color scheme" in the title and the fact that I called the sourced file `colorscheme.vim` may have caused some confusion -- the actual command is something I had never heard of.  My .vimrc goes back more than a decade and I've just occasionally moved parts of it out to other files for sourcing.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your "colorscheme" is missing too many things to be called a "colorscheme". Here is a fixed version:

   ```
   " 'strawberry.vim' -- Vim color scheme.
   " Author:       ...
   " Description:  ...

   hi clear

   if exists("syntax_on")
       syntax reset
   endif

   let colors_name = "strawberry"

   hi Normal guibg=#222228 guifg=#dbdbdb

   set background=dark

   hi ColorColumn guibg=Black guifg=#dbdbdb ctermbg=black ctermfg=yellow
   hi Comment ctermbg=gray ctermfg=darkblue guibg=#dbbdbd guifg=#000088
   hi Conditional cterm=bold ctermfg=yellow gui=bold guifg=#ffff00
   hi Constant ctermfg=brown guifg=#ff8800
   hi Cursor guibg=#ff0000 guifg=#ffff00
   hi Directory ctermfg=gray
   hi DiffAdd guibg=#000044 guifg=#ffff00
   hi DiffChange guibg=#000044 guifg=#aaaaaa
   hi DiffDelete guibg=#000044 guifg=#008888
   hi DiffText guibg=#884400 guifg=#ff8800
   hi ErrorMsg ctermbg=red ctermfg=cyan cterm=bold guibg=#880000 guifg=#ffffff gui=bold
   hi Folded guibg=#00ff00 guifg=#3300aa ctermbg=blue ctermfg=green
   hi Identifier ctermfg=darkgreen gui=none guifg=#449944
   hi LineNr ctermbg=black ctermfg=darkblue guibg=#111111 guifg=#444444
   hi NonText ctermfg=red guifg=#ff8800
   hi Number cterm=underline ctermfg=green gui=underline guifg=#00ff00
   hi PreProc cterm=bold guifg=#cccc88
   hi Repeat cterm=bold ctermfg=cyan gui=bold guifg=#00ffff
   hi StatusLine cterm=bold ctermfg=green ctermbg=darkmagenta guibg=#aa00aa guifg=#00ff00
   hi StatusLineNC ctermfg=7 ctermbg=black
   hi Special ctermfg=magenta gui=bold guifg=#ff0088 guibg=#303030
   hi SpecialKey ctermfg=darkblue guifg=#111111
   hi SpellBad ctermbg=gray ctermfg=darkred
   hi Statement ctermfg=gray guifg=#448888
   hi Type ctermfg=darkcyan guifg=#dd88dd gui=italic
   ```
2. Put your colorscheme in `~/.vim/colors/`:

   ```
   ~/.vim/colors/strawberry.vim
   ```
3. Add this line to your `vimrc` in order to enable your colorscheme:

   ```
   colorscheme strawberry
   ```

Comment: If you would care to explain how this is supposed to be an answer to the question I will reverse my downvote.

Comment: Everything you are doing is wrong and can't work. My answer shows you how to do it right.

Comment: Your answer **EXPLAINS NOTHING**.   I am not interested in this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming "Cut n' paste and trust me" approach.  However, after a little experimentation I did garner something from this which did solve the problem, so if you would care to **explain** that (since I think you know what it is), then I'll accept the answer too.  If not, I'll add my own *explanation* in an answer and leave it at that.  (BTW, "can't work" obviously isn't true, because I've used it this way for *years*, but that is not the issue)

Comment: Everything is explained in various places of Vim's doc, which you are supposed to read; I'd suggest `:help :syn-default-override`. Your "colorscheme" is not a proper colorscheme so I show you how to make it one. That's a solution to your problem #1. You put it in the wrong place and I show you where to put it, that's the solution to your problem #2. You don't call it the right way and i show you how to call it correctly, that's a solution to your problem #3. But I'd say your problem #0 is simply not reading the manual and following your intuition anyway. For this I have no solution.

Comment: Now, if you have further questions on how colorschemes work, I would be happy to answer them as I happen to be a colorscheme author.

Comment: I'm guessing that's why your "answer" reads like, "This is how *I* would write a colorscheme."  **It just looks like someone whats to show off how cool their config is or something.**  So I'm sorry to have been rude but: *I don't care how you would write a colorscheme*.  As per comments on the question, I wasn't even aware of the `colorscheme` command when I wrote the question (notice it is two words in the title, perhaps this led to some confusion).  RTFM ("everything is explained in various places..." just not here) is fine, but it is not an answer, it is a comment.

Comment: And I guess we all have our style of pedentry, but this "style" still rates a -1 from me.  We'll have to agree to disagree about how knowledge is efficiently and effectively communicated.

Comment: @romainl can you list a few of the missing things required for a colourscheme? Say, 5 of them? That would go a long way in improving this answer.

Comment: @muru, no, my answer doesn't need improvement.

Comment: @delicateLatticeworkFever, this is not "how I would write a colorscheme", this is "how colorschemes are written". If you want to write a colorscheme, follow the guidelines laid out in the documentation and you will be fine. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Shouldn't that line read `let g:colors_name = "strawberry"`, since it's a global variable?

Comment: @JohnSchmitt When outside a function, [the default scope is global](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#variable-scope).